# How Fix Custom Page Curl Segue & Show Animations in ViewControllers iOS 6?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uistoryboardsegue, xcode4.6, page-curl

Well the problem that I have now is, how can I create a custom segue, like a modal partial curl?, but in best way like a real page curl segue?, I will try create in a better version using, study from another tutorials but, don't work perfectly or something I do wrong, the other tutorials are in deprecated versions without Storyboard or not use a simple way.

[image]

So  I'm using StoryBoard, XCode 4.6.2 for iOS 6, my project have 3 View Controllers, Im using Navigation Controller, so, each view controller have an image, with custom animation, each time when start each view controller, run the animation in the viewDidLoad, so the partial curl I did Try, are in two Clases, for CurlRight & CurlLeft, so when I run my Project, the Partial or Page Curl Effect run in a different way, because my project is in Landscape mode but how can I use  the AnimationOptionTransitionCurl in right left option in landscape? & the other problem is when I change from View controller to another view controller, running my application, the Animation for each view controller not run not move, but if I push any or another button the image appear in another position like if really moving but not showing in real time WHY?

Im using this code:

```
 // for any ViewController   
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

if (ES_IPAD())
{

}
else
{
    if (ES_IPHONE_5)
    {
       self.imagen.frame = CGRectMake(200, imagen.frame.origin.y, imagen.frame.size.width, imagen.frame.size.height);
    }
    else
    {

    }
}

[self mostrarAnimacion];
}
- (void) mostrarAnimacion
 {

    if (ES_IPAD())
    {

         [UIView animateWithDuration:15.0f delay:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
        imagen.frame = CGRectMake(1024,imagen.frame.origin.y,  imagen.frame.size.width, imagen.frame.size.height);
              } completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        if (ES_IPHONE_5)
        {

            [UIView animateWithDuration:25.0f delay:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
                imagen.frame = CGRectMake(568,imagen.frame.origin.y,  imagen.frame.size.width, imagen.frame.size.height);
            } completion:nil];
        }
        else
        {

            [UIView animateWithDuration:25.0f delay:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
                ViewNubes.frame = CGRectMake(480,imagen.frame.origin.y,  imagen.frame.size.width, imagen.frame.size.height);
            } completion:nil];
        }
    }

}
```

For the Page Curl Effect I create two Clases:

```
#import "PageCurlDerecha.h"

@implementation PageCurlDerecha

-(void)perform
{
UIViewController *Fuente = (UIViewController *)self.sourceViewController;
UIViewController *Destino = (UIViewController *)self.destinationViewController;

[UIView transitionWithView:Fuente.navigationController.view duration:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp animations:^{[Fuente.navigationController pushViewController:Destino animated:NO];} completion:NULL];
}
@end
```

the Other Class

```
@implementation PageCurlIzquierda

-(void)perform
{
UIViewController *Fuente = (UIViewController *)self.sourceViewController;

[UIView transitionWithView:Fuente.navigationController.view duration:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown animations:^{[Fuente.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];} completion:NULL];

}
@end
```

Any HELP?? T_T?? how can I, get a page corner in right down corner effect like a paper page???? So please Guys how can I fix this problems? the page curl for landscape or the animation is like if the left corner from the paper goes to up or down, but not for right left, & for any change viewcontrollers the animation or voids for each viewcontroller not showing, am I Use in wrong way the segues?, or my voids from, viewdidload or dinunload or  view appear are wrong? Thanks a LOT a grettings from Bolivia YOU ROCK guys YOU ROCK!!! XD